# Cross-Dissolve UIImage in UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, uiviewanimationtransition, catransition

I have a UICollectionView that has Cells that contain ImageViews in them. After downloading the images that I want to display in the cell I'd like to cross-dissolve my image with the placeholder image that's already inside the cell.

Everything works as expected, but as sonn as I start reusing the CollectionViews I start seeing strange things.

- The setting of my placeholder image (which is done without the animation) is getting ignored.
- And the image that it's than fading out of is the last image visible (in an other cell) after I make a reload of the collection/table view.

I am currently doing it with the following code:

```
weakSelf.image = placeholderImage;
[UIView transitionWithView:weakSelf
                  duration:5.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                     weakSelf.image = image;
              } completion:nil];
```

but it makes no difference if I do it like that...

```
weakSelf.image = placeholderImage;
CATransition  *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setType:kCATransitionFade];
transition.duration = 5.0;
[weakSelf.layer addAnimation:transition
                      forKey:@"fade"];
weakSelf.image = image;
```

Is it some caching problem of the UIViews presentationLayer?
Is there anything I can do to have my fading in in UICollectionViews or UITableViews?

**EDIT:**

I uploaded a little sample project demonstrating the problem...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/809469/ImageTransition.zip

If you run the Demo-App and hit the reload button on the top right you can see that the images are fading from some random other image. I would think that the fade would be between the same image again... And also the `self.imageView.image = nil;` is somehow ignored?!?!

Comment: the problem is almost certainly in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method (or in your prepareForReuse method if you're subclassing.). Please post those portions of your code.

Comment: I am doing nothing in the `prepareForReuse:` method. It's even not implemented...
But even if I'd set the image to the placeholder image in there, it doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` like this and avoid all the complexity:

```
weakSelf.image = placeholderImage;
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
    weakSelf.alpha=0.0f;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    weakSelf.image = image;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        weakSelf.alpha=1.0f;

    }];
}];
```

don't forget to set  `weakSelf.alpha=1.0f;` and `weakSelf.image = placeholderImage;` in **`prepareForReuse:`**